# Convergent conjecture: What is the proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation, proof-writing, fractions

Lets say that $\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$$K : \nn \to \rr$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{K(i)}{K(i+1)}$ is a convergent sum.

My conjecture is that the function $K$ must be an exponential function.

Can I have a proof of this conjecture?

EDIT: What about if $K$ does not include the factorial function?

Comment: How about $K(n)=(2n-1)!!$ (double factorial)?  If you want continuity on the reals, then you can extend $K$ countinously.

Comment: $K$ may be an arbitrary functions; your condition is only sum $\sum \frac{K(n)}{K(n+1)}$ converges

Comment: If you mean 'exponential' in the sense that $K(n)$ (note that $K$ doesn't have to be defined anywhere but the integers) must grow at least exponentially - i.e., $K(n)\geq e^{Cn}$ for some constant $C$ and all sufficiently large $n$ - then not only this is true but in fact you can show that $K(n)$ is _super_ exponential - the previous statement is true for _all_ constants $C$.

Comment: Observe that your question is much more concise and easy to read now. Also, note that originally you did not specify that the terms were real numbers, but you probably meant that. It's important to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple proof that $K(n)$ is not only exponential but 'super' exponential in the sense that for all constants $C$, there is some $n_0$ such that $|K(n)|\geq C^n$ for all $n\gt n_0$.  Let's rewrite your series as $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ so that we don't run out of indices; in other words, $K(n)=a_n$.  (For convenience's sake I'm going to take $a_n$ positive for all $n$; this doesn't really affect the argument, but it's what requires the use of the absolute-value brackets above.)

Now, by the definition of a convergent series, the limit of the terms is 0; $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=0$.  In particular, given any constant $C$, we know that there exists a $n_0$ such that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\leq\frac1C$ for all $n\gt n_0$.  But by cross-multiplication, this is equivalent to $a_{n+1}\geq Ca_n$ for all $n\gt n_0$; then by induction this implies that $a_{n_0+k}\geq C^k a_{n_0}$ for all $k$, or (shifting indices) that $a_n\geq DC^n$, where $D=C^{-n_0}a_{n_0}$.  This is the result that we want 'up to a constant factor' (that factor of $D$), but that's not really relevant here - note that we could have just chosen $C$ 'twice as big' as we needed to (since this result holds for all $C$) and by the relative exponential growth of $(2C)^n$ vs $C^n$ we can eventually wipe out the constant $D$.